# How does Spring boot put Thymeleaf view resolver into its bean container

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

It is a spring boot project and the web page is rendered by Thymeleaf. When I put spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf in the pom.xml and start the applicaiton, it is trying to find all the beans which implements ViewResolver in its container. And you see here it find thymeleafViewResolver.

I am just curious that when and how does Spring boot put this ThymeleafViewResolver class into its bean container?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to SpringBoot [auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-auto-configuration) feature which will automatically create a bean dynamically based on [different conditions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-condition-annotations) such as if a library can be found from the class paths, or if developers already define a bean of certain type etc...

If you turn on the debug mode by putting `debug=true` in the `application.properties` , it will print out a report during application startup saying which beans are auto created due to which conditions.

In the example of the `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` , you can find the following from the report :

```
ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.ThymeleafWebMvcConfiguration.ThymeleafViewResolverConfiguration#thymeleafViewResolver matched:
                  - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: thymeleafViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)
```

And by tracing the source codes of `ThymeleafViewResolverConfiguration` :

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "thymeleafViewResolver")
public ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(this.templateEngine);
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding(this.properties.getEncoding().name());
    //.......   
    return resolver;
}
```

You could find out `thymeleafViewResolver` is in a type of `ThymeleafViewResolver` and [`@ConditionalOnMissingBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-bean-conditions) here means that this bean will only be created if there is no bean of the `ThymeleafViewResolver` type is defined yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I googled a lot pages to study auto-config. It is really cool!

Comment: For your post, which version of the auto-config are you referring to? The content of ThymeleafViewResolverConfiguration is a bit different with my version, which is spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.17.RELEASE.jar

Comment: I am using 2.1.X version but the idea is the same.